# What happened to the Apollo 1 rocket?

Tags: rockets, apollo-program, failure

On January 27, 1967, a tragic fire killed the crew of Apollo 1 and destroyed the Command Module. I've read detailed reports about the engineering team that disassembled the Command Module. I haven't been able to find information about what happened to the rocket that was attached to the Command Module during the fire. Was it reused in a future mission? If so, which mission?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is one case where [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_1) says it all:

> Apollo 1's (AS-204) Saturn IB rocket was taken down from Launch Complex 34, later reassembled at Launch complex 37B and used to launch Apollo 5, an unmanned Earth orbital test flight of the first lunar module, LM-1, in January 1968 [65].

The Wikipedia article cites the following primary reference:

"Apollo Program" (http://www.nasm.si.edu/research/arch/findaids/bellcomm/bci_sec_21.html). National Air and Space Museum. Bellcomm, Inc Technical Library Collection. Washington, D.C.: Smithsonian Institution. 2001. Subseries III.D.3. Accession No. XXXX-0093. Retrieved January 26, 2013.

Comment: I wonder if there was a deliberate decision not to fly another CSM on that Saturn IB - it carried only the LM and an aerodynamic shroud atop the adapter.

Comment: That would have depended on the mission plan.